# Tether laptop to Android Pulse Secure

Tags: tethering, vpn, wifi-tethering, usb-tethering

I am using Ubuntu at the moment, and cannot get my company's VPN to work reliably using openconnect. I can, however, connect via the Pulse Connect Android app.

Clearly, I could then tether my laptop to my phone. I'm not interested in adding tethering to my phone plan.

I really only need to use this setup over WiFi (no need to use cellular data or involve the phone company).

I imagine there is some way to route my laptop's connection to the VPN via my phone without using cellular data.

When I disable cellular data and enable USB tethering in settings, the modal hangs, presumably because it is trying to check with the phone company over their network for "permission".

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What Android device and version are you using?  (Have you tried using Juniper Network Connect rather than openconnect?)

Comment: Nexus 5x L. Network Connect is what I used to use (successfully) prior to my company's IT dept. rolling out Pulse Secure. :-/